# Remove last char if it's a specific character

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I need to update values in a table by removing their last char if they ends with a `+`

**Example:**
`John+Doe` and `John+Doe+` should both become `John+Doe`.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to update the value or just remove it in a query?

Comment: Sorry @GordonLinoff my bad. I want to update the value in the table.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
UPDATE table 
SET field = SUBSTRING(field, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(field) - 1) 
WHERE field LIKE '%+'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to display the field instead of update the table,  then you can use a `CASE` statement:

```
select 
  case 
    when right(yourfield,1) = '+' then left(yourfield,length(yourfield)-1) 
    else yourfield end
from yourtable
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71533/3)

Answer (score 0):

you didn't explain exactly the situation.
but if you search for names in a text. I'll remove all the non chars (anything not a-z and A-Z) including spaces and then compare.

if you want just the last char, try the SUBSTRING_INDEX function.

Answer (score 0):

if you are passing to the DB as a string, you can do this with str_replace

```
<?php
$str = "John+Doe+";
$str = str_replace("+"," ",$str); 
echo  $str;
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this replace both +?

Comment: it replaces ALL the "+" within the given string

Comment: But I need to keep the +, except if it's at the end of the string.

Comment: so just replace the end +?

Comment: if so, just use rtrim
    <?php
    $str = "John+Doe+";
    $str = rtrim($str, '+');
    echo $str;
    ?>